# Why is the search bar pushing the navigation bar out of the picture?

Tags: swift

I added a `UISearchBar` programmatically to my view and every time you activate the `searchBar` the navigation bar is pushed out of the picture.

[image]

[image]

[**My view's hierarchy**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6Sas.jpg)

```
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

    navigationItem.title = navigationItem.title ?? ci("plan_p")

    tableView.rowHeight = 100.0
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: (self.tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame.size.height)!), animated: false)

    guard let projectId = GlobalState.selectedProjectId, let byProject : Results<Structure> = self.by(projectId: projectId) else { return }

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Suche nach Plan"
    definesPresentationContext = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your `UITableView` is top of the view hierarchy (or more components in top of the view hierarchy).

If your tableView in top of the view hierarchy you should change the tableView's hierarchy in your `Interface Builder` for solve this issue.

You can simply put your tableView in another `UIView` component for solve this issue.

Comment: I add my `searchBar` programmatically to the `headerView` of my `tableView`. The top space of my `tableView` is constrained to the bottom space of my `stackView`. I do not know why the search bar pushed the `stackView` out of the screen. Hierarchy is: `View`-> `StackView` -> `TableView`

Comment: Hi @Preefix. Please share your view hierarchy `Interface Builder`'s screen shot for better understand. I think your tableView is in the same hierarchy to your stackView.

Comment: Your tableView in same hierarchy with your stackView. Please check my edit @Preefix . I hope it works.

Comment: I did it like [this](https://imgur.com/a/l08IISI)  but my search bar is still pushing my stack view out of the picture like shown above.

Comment: Delete `Top and Bottom Layout Guide`, use `Safe Area`. And then you should set your view's(which is the with tableview) top and bottom constraints to superView (which is the First View of your viewController)

Comment: Im running my project in iOS 9.1 unfortunately.. so no safe area here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196207/discussion-between-emre-ciftci-and-preefix).

Comment: I gave some additional info in the discussion chat